# Texstudio bibtex compile chapterwise bib file

Tags: bibtex, chapters, texstudio, thesis

I am writing a thesis in Latex that include different chapters with separate tex files. Note the following:

- Folder structure

```
├── Chapters
│   └── Chapter1
│       ├── chapter1.tex
│       └── mybib.bib
└── thesis.tex
```

- `thesis.tex` file

```tex
\documentclass[a4,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\begin{document}
\include{Chapters/Chapter1/chapter1}
\end{document}
```

- `chapter1.tex` file:

```tex
\chapter{Test}
This is a sample chapter with \cite{my_article}

\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{mybib}
```

- `mybib.bib` file:

```
@article{my_article,
    author = {Test Author},
    title = {Article title},
    journal = {J. Chem. Phys.},
    volume = {100},
    pages = {1000},
    year = {2000}
}
```

First, I run the `build` command of TexStudio in `thesis.tex`, the `bibtex` throws error

```
Process started: bibtex "thesis".aux

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2019/Debian)
The top-level auxiliary file: thesis.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: Chapters/Chapter1/chapter1.aux
The style file: plain.bst
I couldn't open database file mybib.bib
---line 4 of file Chapters/Chapter1/chapter1.aux
 : \bibdata{mybib
 :               }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no database files---while reading file thesis.aux
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "my_article"
(There were 2 error messages)
```

Meaning TexStudio can not find the `mybib.bib` file. So I modified the bibliography line as this

```tex
\bibliography{Chapters/Chapter1/mybib}
```

Now if I compile, the bibtex complies properly

```
Process started: bibtex "thesis".aux

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2019/Debian)
The top-level auxiliary file: thesis.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: Chapters/Chapter1/chapter1.aux
The style file: plain.bst
Database file #1: Chapters/Chapter1/mybib.bib

Process exited normally
```

But the bibliography is not included. How to solve this in TexStudio ? How to manage/compile in this kind of situation.

Now if I keep the bibliography line as before and manually run `bibtex chapter1.aux` from terminal in the `Chapters/Chapter1` folder and then run the build command in the `thesis.tex` file, it works. Can this be done in the TexStudio itself ?

Comment: My guess is that you do not set any  path  to `mybib.bib` in the main document  as you do for the includes, so it try to read `./mybib.bib` (i.e., the working directory)   instead of   `./Chapters/chapter1/mybib.bib`, but without code to see, is just a guessing game. Please add a minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB).

Comment: I have modified the question. Check if you can understand the problem now @Fran

Comment: Do you know that you must  run the compiler (e..g., pdflatex) also after bibtex,  at least two times more?